# How to get align textview to parent bottom

Tags: android, coding-style

I want to set the "date_text" bottom to that of its parent bottom but it taking the bottom of the main parent. I tried following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/Layout">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<!-- Month and Year on the top -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#22C778"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="December 2014"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/month_name"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<!-- Date and Month On The Left -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="30 Jan"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/date_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/month_name"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

<!-- Question Title  -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="This Is The Title Of Question Of January"
    android:id="@+id/question_title"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/date_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_text" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried using layoutalignParentBottom="true" but it isn't working

Comment: This question is an old question, and at that time, we do not have the `Constraint Layout`. However, now you can do it easily by using constraint layout. For more information, you can look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout). I am writing this comment for others who want to do the same thing and find this question. I hope you have an idea now. Hava a beautiful day guys!

Answer (score 0):

You have a `RelativeLayout` inside another `RelativeLayout` which seems redundant if you're not going to add anything more. If you actually need it then set the height of inner `RelativeLayout` to `match parent`. For the textview the parent is the inner `RelativeLayout` and since its height is `wrap_content` it will expand to only the height required

Comment: The outer Relative Layout is the main content and will contain many child Relative Layout for each question.

Comment: Have you closed the `RelativeLayouts` appropriately?

Comment: It seems to be working for me.. Also for your use case you should be using a listview and set the questions as row items and set the layout for the row items accordingly

Comment: Can you tell me what happens when you add more children?

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/Layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- Month and Year on the top -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#22C778"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="December 2014"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <!-- Date and Month On The Left -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/month_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#F1F1F1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="30 Jan"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <!-- Question Title -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_text"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="This Is The Title Of Question Of January" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this is what you want....

Comment: Just try and let me know, is this what you want, And Sorry if i misunderstood your query.

Comment: Thanks for your effort bro but i the question description length can vary accordingly. So i want it to take the height of that description. It's bottom should match the description bottom.